# Spring AOP advices around objects returned by Hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate, aop, pointcut

Spring AOP advises are NOT kicking off around methods of objects returned by hibernate.

In my program, hibernate is returning list of objects of type CFolder.

What I want is when somebody calls getName() method on CFolder objects returned by the hibernate, I want Spring AOP to write "Before getName()" and "After getName()".

CFolder that represents folder

```
public class CFolder{
    String name;

    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }
}
```

Repository class that finds all the CFolders

```
@Service
@Repository
public class MyService implements MyServiceIfc<TypeTemplateMasterRepository> {

    @Autowired
    private CFolderRepository cfolderRepository;

    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly=true)
    public void findAll(Class classz) throws Exception {

        List allFolders = cfolderRepository.findAll(); //Use hibernate to find all folders..
        for(int i=0; i < allFolders.size(); i++){
            CFolder cFolder = (CFolder) allFolders.get(i);
            System.out.println("The folder name is" + cFolder.getName()); //When 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring will only be able to proxy beans (apply AOP) which it controls, basically AOP will only work for beans inside the `ApplicationContext`.

If you want other objects intercepted you will need to use AspectJ and revert to either loadtime or compile time weaving of your aspects.

Comment: Thank you - Just wondering if you have a Hello World example of how to achieve this..Have been struggling quite a bit on this one.

Comment: Also - is there a way to import or induct objects return by hibernate in Spring's ApplicationContext or say make it Spring Managed. If so is there an overhead?

Comment: No there isn't... The objects aren't spring managed and spring will never be able to touch them, not without loadtime/compile time weaving.